# How to convert unary fractional digits to binary fractional digits (is there a way?)

Tags: converters

I worked out how how to convert unary integers to binary integers by grouping pairs with or without rest.

an example is given here by the decimal value of 9

```
LW                      RW
0a) 111111111         | ->
0b) 1(11)(11)(11)(11) |
1a)    1   1   1   1  | 1  (by no rest the RW (right value would be 0)
1b)   (1   1) (1   1) |
2a)        1       1  | 0 1 
2b)       (1       1) |
3a)                1  | 0 0 1
4)                    | 1 0 0 1  (which is 9)
```

Can you help me find the äquivalent form for the convertation of fractional unary digits to binary ones? Is there a possibility?
thx in advance

Comment: What do you mean by fractional unary digits? Also, for what you show here, why not just count the number of unary digits and represent it in binary? Is this related to a particular programming language?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_coding there is a way to code unary by a representation of only one state of a unit - it is possible for integers represented like that to convert them directly to digits but i found no method for converting float in general - no specific language

Comment: So here's what I got out of that article: > Unary coding, sometimes called thermometer code, is an entropy encoding that represents a natural number, n, with n ones followed by a zero (if natural number is understood as non-negative integer) ...

Comment: That's the first sentence. How do you get fractions out of this?

Comment: I found out if using the float part in reverse you can go keep the unary system  because there whouldn't be any leading 0 that can't be representet

Comment: So what is 11111 as a unary fraction? How do you represent 1/3? How about 2/3?

Comment: why not? electricity used in another way - what is wrong in a discrete number space to sum 1/3 your kiddin me, right?

Comment: I'm asking you for a concrete implementation. What sequence of bits uniquely identify 1/3 and 2/3 in your system. If I understood how you want to represent those fractions, I'd be able to help you.

Comment: there is at least one symbol for null but not used in a number, null just represents no information. The implementation I suggest is using groups of ones for unary signs which sum is the number in decimal but when the calculation gives a floating point number as result there has to be a discrete maximum of ones which are read reverse from right to left as sum so given 2/3 0.6 is null.111111 and 0.6666...6 to the discrete maximum length of ones giving 6666...6 increased in reverse so 0.0125 whould be null. fifethousandtohunderedone.